# Help identifying. Is this a weed?

Tags: weeds

Looks like flat leaf parsley, has small purple flowers. [image]

Comment: Weeds are only undesired plants in the eye of the beholder, be more specific please.

Comment: a picture of the flowers would help

Comment: Its fast growing and crowding my garden. It hasn’t flowered yet, I opened one up to look and it was purple.

Comment: How big are the leaves? Looks ground ivy-ish to me.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like a Geranium of some variety (assuming its not producing tall flowering stems, when it might be Delphinium); these are hardy herbaceous perennials, and not to be confused with Pelargonium, which has the common name of geranium. All varieties spread to differing extents, and some seed themselves readily; most tolerate shade, but prefer partial shade. There are hundreds of varieties, not sure which one this is, seeing open flowers would be helpful, as well as knowing the height. This link https://www.gardenia.net/guide/Long-Blooming-Hardy-Geraniums-for-your-Garden lists some varieties of Geranium, though judging by the foliage, I don't think yours is one of them. If its got too big, you can dig it up, split it in half and replant one of the halves... but that's  best done in early spring or mid to late autumn, so if you do it now, keep the replanted section well watered.